# Display property not changing to 'none' using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I am facing a weird issue here. It might be a very silly mistake that I am doing.

```js
function addTrainer() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('add-trainers-form');
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  $(this).click(function(event) { //this part of code works fine, 
    $('.modal').css('display', 'block');
  });

  $(span).click(function(event) { //not working
    // modal.style.display = "none";
    $('.modal').css('display', 'inherit');
  });

  $(window).click(function(event) { //this also works fine
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  });

  $('#add-trainer-btn').click(function() { //not working
    $('.modal').css('display', 'none');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="add-trainers-controls">
    <div class="add-remove-control">

      <input id="add-trainer" type="image" src="img/add5.png" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48" onclick="addTrainer()">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="add-trainers-form" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span id="close" class="close">&times;</span>
      <p>Add Trainers</p>
      <input class="textStyle" type="text" placeholder="Username">
      <input class="textStyle" type="text" placeholder="Email">
      <button id="add-trainer-btn" class="buttonStyle" type="button">Add</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on `#add-trainer` button, modal pops up. Its default `css` property is set to `display:none`. After clicking it is set to `display:block`. When I click anywhere outside the modal window, display property is reset to `none`. But the same needs to be done with `#add-trainer-btn` and `#close` button which is not working.

Comment: Your chances of receiving an answer will be greatly improved if you add a Codepen demonstrating the issue

Comment: When are you calling the function?

Comment: You main problem is the you are triggering multiple events at one time so you are covering up one event action with another.  For example, you click on any button, it is within the scope of the window click event so it also gets fired so it appears that the "none" is not working. Well it is for a split second

Comment: i am calling the function onclick of the #add-trainer image button.

Comment: okay so the issue is solved. Thanks for co-operation. :)

Comment: I just passed 'this' when i was calling the function. It solved the problem.